# LNK2019 error building ZeroMQ Hello World example. VS2012 RC

Tags: c++, linker-errors, zeromq, visual-studio-2012

I get the following error trying to build the "hello world" example from ZeroMQ.

```
Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zmq_msg_init
referenced in function _wmain
```

I've added the library and header paths to the project (BTW how do I add them to the default settings?) and I've tried adding "libzmq-v100-mt.lib" (and "libzmq-v100-mt-gd.lib") to the linker additional inputs property. This didn't help.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The ZeroMQ headers ([`zmq.h` in particular](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq2-x/blob/master/include/zmq.h#L36)), by default, appear only to support dynamic linking on win32.

Try `#define`-ing `ZMQ_EXPORT`. That way, it won't see the `__declspec(dllimport)` declaration and won't expect to link against a `.dll`.